# Passing an array from Blade to controller: Undefined index when accessing elements

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass an array (originated from a custom config file) from a blade template to a controller to process it into a form field. The config array should act like a 'template' so that forms easily can be created by altering the config file.

While passing the array seems to work it is impossible for me to access it's elements (Undefined index).

**(part of) The config file**

```
return [

    'tabs' => [

        'Menu'     => [
            'name'    => 'menu',
            'type'    => 'string',
            'length'  => 100,
            'default' => null
        ],
        ...
    ]

]
```

**In my Blade template I am iterating this array calling a controller function:**

```
@foreach($tabs as $key => $fld)
    {!! \App\Classes\Fields::createField($key, $fld, $page) !!}
@endforeach
```

**The controller (simplyfied):**

```
class Fields
{
    public static function createField($key, $fld, $page)
    {
        var_dump($fld);

        // Result-------------------------------

        // array (size=4)
        //   'name' => string 'menu' (length=4)
        //   'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
        //   'length' => int 100
        //   'default' => null        }

        var_dump($fld['name']);

        // Result-------------------------------    

        // ErrorException in Fields.php line 19: 
        // Undefined index: name
        // (The other elements also can't be accessed)

}
```

I really don't understand. Var_dump shows a valid array while it's elements can't be accessed. I am pulling my hair out for some hours. Is this a Laravel bug or am I buggy myself? ;-)

Comment: Because `$fld` is an **array** that contains 4 elements that have the keys `name`, `type`, `length`, and `default`. Pay attention to your code and read it carefully. You meant to say `$fld["Menu"]["name"]` and not `$fld["name"]`.

Comment: you used `$fld` in foreach and `{!! \App\Classes\Fields::createField($key, $field, $page) !!}` you use `$field`. Change it. This will solve your issue.

Comment: could you try looping through the `$fld` variable within your `createField()` static method: just to see what you get? `foreach($fld as $k=>$v){var_dump($k); var_dump($v);};`  This could help see what's going on...

Comment: @Manish, this was a typo on stack, in the real code it is/was correct.

Comment: And also your `$page` in **createField** method in controller section is missing. why you did so much mistakes in it?

Comment: @Poiz: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  (Same problem as in the controller)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping through your `$fld` Array within your `createField()` Method to see the result? This could give you a little insight on the bug...

**BLADE**

```
    @foreach($tabs as $key => $fld)
        {!! \App\Classes\Fields::createField($key, $fld, $page) !!}
    @endforeach
```

**SIMPLIFIED CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

    class Fields {


        public static function createField($key, $fld, $page){
            // JUST FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES: TRY THIS & SEE WHAT YOU GET.
            // BUT CHECK FIRST IF $fld IS AN ARRAY
            if( is_array($fld) ){
                foreach($fld as $key=>$value){    
                    var_dump($key);
                    var_dump($value);
                }
            }else{
                // OTHERWISE, TRY DETERMINING THE TYPE OF $fld
                var_dump("\$fld IS AN OBJECT? ", is_object($fld));
                var_dump("\$fld IS A  STRING? ", is_string($fld));
            }

            var_dump($fld);
            var_dump($fld['name']);
        }
    }
```

> **UPDATE**

```
    <?php

        class Fields {

            public static function createField($key, $fld, $page){
                // CREATE VARIABLES FOR EACH EXPECTED VALUE(S):
                // INITIALIZE THEM TO NULL...
                $name = $type = $length = $default = null;
                // JUST FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES: TRY THIS & SEE WHAT YOU GET.
                // BUT CHECK FIRST IF $fld IS AN ARRAY
                if( is_array($fld) ){
                    foreach($fld as $key=>$value){
                        switch($key){
                            case "name":
                                $name       = $value;
                                break;
                            case "type":
                                $type       = $value;
                                break;
                            case "length":
                                $length     = $value;
                                break;
                            case "default":
                                $default    = $value;
                                break;                          
                        }                           
                    }
                }
                echo $name;
                echo $type;
                echo $length;
                echo $default;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  (Changed $field to $fld in your code to keep Manish happy :-) )

Comment: Perhaps you might want to try the loop within an `if(){}else{}` Block as the updated code depicts....

Comment: Now we are heading somewhere, If I enclose the foreach is_array($fld) it is working! Strange though because it is always an array and there is only one call to it...

Comment: var_dump($fld['name']); still isn't working: Undefined index: name. Even if I use the working foreach loop: echoing $value['name']: Undefined index: name. I am not getting the logic here...

Comment: @klaaz No... You don't `echo $value['name'];` anymore because you are within a Loop... check out the Updated code for more insight...